# Haproxy hdr_ip acl unaffected by reqidel?

Tags: haproxy

I have an server that sits behind a load balancer, but for the time being can also be accessed directly.

I have a white list of IP addresses that should be able to access it.

Given the following configuration:

```
frontend http
  bind 0.0.0.0:80

  acl from_internal src 10.0.0.0/8
  reqidel ^X-Cluster-Client-Ip unless from_internal

  acl ip_allow src -f /etc/haproxy/allow.txt
  acl lb_allow hdr_ip(X-Cluster-Client-Ip) -f /etc/haproxy/allow.txt

  http-request allow if ip_allow
  http-request allow if lb_allow
  http-request deny
```

I want to allow direct requests from certain IP's (`ip_allow`). I want to allow requests that the load balancer has set `X-Cluster-Client-Ip` for (`lb_allow`).

However, I only want to trust that header from the load balancer (`10.0.0.0/8`). In all other cases, I just want to delete it.

It seems like the header is not deleted when applying the ACL - if I set `X-Cluster-Client-Ip` to a trusted IP and connect directly to the server then I get through. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you cannot rely on header manipulation to affect ACLs - they are not applied in order after mangling.

In you case you can easily amend the logic

```
http-request allow if ip_allow
http-request allow if lb_allow from_internal
http-request deny
```